# How to hold a value on java

Tags: java

This is my first month on java. I got a logical error that updates the this value each time I call the method.How can I fix this and make static so each time the original data and time is not change.

result:

```
testing 7 arg constructor with initial date: [2-28-2015],[12:30:30:0]
Increasing day by 366 [2-29-2016],[12:30:30:0]
Increasing  month by 12 [2-28-2017],[12:30:30:0]<---- should be 2016
Increasing  year by 2 [2-28-2019],[12:30:30:0]<-------should be 2017
Initial date is [2-28-2016],[12:30:30:0]
Increasing day by 365 [2-27-2017],[12:30:30:0]
Increasing  month by 11 [1-27-2018],[12:30:30:0]
Increasing  year by 30 [1-27-2048],[12:30:30:0]
```

here is my code:

```
public class DateTime implements DateConstants {    
private  Date date; // from Date Class
private  Time time; // from Time class
}
public  DateTime addMonths(int mo)
{
this.date.addMonths(mo);
return this;
}
public static void main(String[] myArgs) {
dateTime1 = new DateTime(2,28,2015,12,30,30,0);
System.out.println("testing 7 arg constructor with initial date: "+dateTime1);
System.out.println("Increasing day by 366 "+dateTime1.addDays(366));
System.out.println("Increasing  month by 12 "+dateTime1.addMonths(12));
System.out.println("Increasing  year by 2 "+dateTime1.addYears(2));
}
```

Comment: 'static' is entirely the wrong word to use here. It already has a well-defined meaning, and this isn't it.

Comment: you mean, public static final DateTime addMonths(int mo)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want your additions to add to the base value that the object was created with. Right now, you have one object that is maintaining its state through execution, so when you say `dateTime1.addDays(366)`, it's modifying that object permanently.

You'll have to either put in functionality to hold onto the values passed into the constructor to "reset" to, or re-instantiate the `DateTime` object after every modification.

As others have said, there is a meaning to the word `static`, and this is not appropriate. Please change your title.

Comment: yes you catch my point. Let me see what will be the solution then.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly your question, I think you can try this

```
public class DateTime implements DateConstants {    
 private  Date date; // from Date Class
 private  Time time; // from Time class

 }
public  DateTime addMonths(int mo)
{
  DateTime temp=this.clone();
  return temp.date.addMonths(mo);

}
public static void main(String[] myArgs) {
dateTime1 = new DateTime(2,28,2015,12,30,30,0);
System.out.println("testing 7 arg constructor with initial date: "+dateTime1);
System.out.println("Increasing day by 366 "+dateTime1.addDays(366));
System.out.println("Increasing  month by 12 "+dateTime1.addMonths(12));
System.out.println("Increasing  year by 2 "+dateTime1.addYears(2));
}
```

Comment: still gives same result.

Answer (score 0):

if you re-create the object before each system.out, you'll get the result you want.

it seems that your object is being reused

The declaration of "dateTime1" is missing from your code, and then we assume it´s a class attribute, but you should show in your question where it is declared.